# How to get specific occurences of a string in a text and put it in an array?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a long text which contains:

```
city_nameLAcity_name some text here and there ;) city_nameLondoncity_name some other text will goes here too then city_nameTehrancity_name and of course some other junk text here.
```

I want to slurp LA, London, and Tehran from the text above. I ereg, but couldn't get what I want I used something like below:

```
ereg ("city_name(.*)city_name", $longText, $output);
```

How to do this job? I appreciate your inputs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `(.*?)` instead of `(.*)`. The difference is that `.*` will match as much as possible (using the greedy quantifier `*`) while `.*?` will match as *little* as possible (`*?` is a *lazy* quantifier). So unless you have a city whose name includes `city_name` somewhere (dunno, the US has some strange names; maybe it happens) `.*?` should get you what you want.

Random note: This might not work with [`ereg`](http://php.net/ereg), I'm not intimately familiar with extended POSIX regular expressions right now. However, those functions are deprecated in PHP for a while now (and you should get a warning about that, too). It's better to replace them by the various `preg_*` functions where possible. The substitute would be [`preg_match_all`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), I believe.

Comment: When I use `preg_match_all ("city_name(.*?)city_name", $longText, $output);` it says: `Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash`

Comment: I used `/city_name(.*?)city_name/`, and it solved my problem and a now a new problem: it returns `city_nameLAcity_name` and `LA`!

Comment: Of course it does. PCRE have delimiters within the string. Most often `/`, i.e. you need `preg_match_all("/city_name(.*?)city_name/", $longText, $output);`. You can also use braces, if I remember correctly and note that the delimiter must be escaped if it appears in the pattern but you can also use a different one (`#` is often used for patterns matching paths or URIs).

Comment: How to get just LA,London,Tehran instead of city_nameLAcity_name, LA, etc? thanks for the effort.

Comment: Well, you are matching `city_name` as well as what comes in between. You're just putting the stuff in between in a capturing group. But the match itself is longer. You can use lookaround to change that but I wouldn't recommend it here. Just use the first group from each match instead.